# How to set variables for `dotnet new`?

Tags: c#, .net

Standard template for command

`dotnet new console`

contains #if for the preprocessor:

```
#if (csharpFeature_TopLevelProgram)
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
#endif
#if (!csharpFeature_ImplicitUsings)
using System;

#endif
#if (csharpFeature_TopLevelProgram)
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
#else
namespace Company.ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

What command line switches should I specify to `dotnet new` so that the variable "csharpFeature_TopLevelProgram" is not defined and so that when I execute `dotnet new console` the file is generated not for Net6 but without TopLevelProgram as before in the good old Net5?

Comment: Create your own template? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-template-package

Comment: There is already template exists. But what should I use to have #ifdef inside already existed template works?

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `-h` command line option, it tells you how to use the template and that you can specify the `--use-program-main` parameter:

[image]

For example:

```
dotnet new console --use-program-main true
```

***Note**: You may need to update to a newer version of .NET 6 for this command line option to exist. This was tested with v6.0.401*

Comment: This does not work for me:

    Error: Invalid option(s):
    --use-program-main
       '--use-program-main' is not a valid option

Comment: It works fine for me, [here's proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyUZz.png). Are you sure you got the parameters in the right order?

Comment: I have the proof also: http://pics.rsh.ru/img/Screenshot_2022-09-27_06-47-59_6xj45i8n.png And yes, my dotnet has no such parameters.

Comment: Maybe try updating your SDK with the latest one? I'm not sure when they added that option.

Comment: My  dotnet 6.0.108 has no such option but dotnet 6.0.401 has. The issue is closed.